# Flutter + Firebase paswordless authentication not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement passwordless authentication in my Flutter app using dynamic links, but the link the app receives always returns false for the `isSignInWithEmailLink()` method.
The dynamic link I created in the firebase console is the following:
[Dynamic Links configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDhCT.png)

And the code I am using to send it is:

```
var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
        url: "https://XXXXXX.page.link/eP3A",
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOSBundleId: "com.example.XXXXX",
        androidPackageName: "com.example.XXXXXX",
        androidInstallApp: true,
        androidMinimumVersion: "12",
    );

    FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
        email: email, actionCodeSettings: acs)
        .catchError((onError) =>
        print('Error sending email verification $onError'))
        .then((value) => print('Successfully sent email verification'));
```

I am able to receive the link in the email, and when clicking on it, it opens the app. However, the link always return false in `isSignInWithEmailLink()`. Am I missing something? I've tried different combinations on the ActionCodeSettings object but none of them seem to work. I am using the latest versions of `firebase_auth` and `firebase_dynamic_links`.

Comment: You also have to allow permission at your project level for sign in with email link. Have you done it?

Comment: Yes, I have done that

Comment: try to raise androidMinimumVersion: "12", to '23'

Comment: Didn't work. I have debugged it and it seems like the app always receives the URL that I configured under "Deep Link URL" in Firebase console instead of the sign in URL that I am actually receiving in the email.

Comment: Also, I have tried the same ActionCodeSettings in a Python and Node script and both of them work, i.e.: If I create the link in the same manner but from outside the application, the link I receive in the app actually signs in the user.

Comment: does your package name exactly matches the one that you had registered on Firebase? It is critical. You can find your package name in build.gradle for example.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely the same, otherwise I think the app wouldn't even open when clicking the link

Comment: I will take a closer look in the upcoming 72 hours if you can wait